# Issue with Pure Virtual function called by library

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am facing a weird issue. I will explain my situation.

I am working on a hardware platform and have the custom toolchain.
I have a library given by the vendor that we make use of to call specific callback functions defined in a header file.

it is something like

```
    virtual void callbackfn(arg1, arg2) = 0;
```

the standard pure virtual function declaration.

the vendor says that he has re defined the body in the class that has derived it.

Compilation is successful. However, during the runtime, the program becomes    dead and the error thrown is that  a null pointer is used to refer the structure and says a bad value address.

I would be extremely grateful if someone could help me with a work around.
Do I have to ask the vendor to modify the library and give me. if yes can you please suggest the changes.
Or is it a tool chain issue? do we need to add any flags/ modification in tool chain.

Comment: Are the library and the application using it both built using the same compiler and version with the same settings? If not, there can be a misalignment of the virtual table or various member variables which could cause an issue like this to occur. It will compile, but not all the structures and classes will have all the methods and instance variables at the same offsets.

Comment: *"program becomes dead and the error thrown is that a null pointer is used to refer the structure"* - refer to *which* structure?  What you describe sounds more like a `nullptr` dereference having nothing to do with the pure virtual function.

Comment: it is built using the same compiler and version. Is there any way to get the address of the said function in the virtual table?